# force invalid html to stay inside parent div regardless of CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm curious if it is possible to force HTML that is missing one or more end tags to "stay" within its parent `div`.

For instance:

```
<!-- parent div-->
<div id="parent">
   <div>this is super wrong.....
</div>
<!-- more html that I don't want affected by the super wrong html-->
```

Essentially I would want the above code to not break the layout of the page.

Comment: Which version of HTML ? What do you exactly mean with "to stay within its parent div" ?

Comment: html5 - by stay within its parent div i mean that regardless of the content within the parent div the parent div will remain the same thus the html around the parent div will not be altered - kind of like CDATA in xml

Comment: Fixed formatting and typos. Completed last sentence.

Comment: Some browsers try to work around the mess, but the result is not predictable. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to guarantee this in all browsers. When code does not follow the standards browsers have to guess what was intended by the code. It is not going to know which `<div>` you forgot to close, but it does take a guess. Different types of browsers will guess differently and render your code differently if it does not align to the standards.

If you are allowing user inputted code I would highly recommend using a validator to validate the document. Here are some manual validators:

https://validator.w3.org/

https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

but if you are accepting code through a backend scripting language, you would be better off using a related module. Here is an example of a document validator for PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php